# Generate random weights vector with fixed sum

Tags: r, vector, random

What I need:
I want to create a 10 size vector with random weights. The sum of weights should be equal to 1.

Why I need that:
I want to finally calculate the returns of stocks of a randomly diversified portfolio of assets.

Mock Solution:
[0.01 0.02 0.07 0.10 0.10 0.05 0.05 .......]. Sum of all elements is 1.

Comment: `w <- runif(10); w <- w/sum(w)` Use any different distribution as appropriate.

Comment: Any distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
x <- runif(10)
weights <- x/sum(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) exactly does what you want.

```r
igraph::sample_dirichlet(1, alpha = rep(1, 10L))
```